# Time travel, pre historic book title search. Characters named Mark and Umsee

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for a book, read about 1995-2000 where the main character Mark is struck by lightning in modern day Dallas and woke up in primitive Texas, about 1000 years earlier. He travels east to Hot Springs in Arkansas. Meets a man named Umsee and his wolf and lives with the people there.

On his travels he crosses the Red River and is caught in a bad flash flood. He continues on east because he and his wife had been to Hot Springs in modern times. He knew it would be mild during the winter.

Umsee was the early Indian caretaker of the Hot Springs for the families that only wintered there. Through Umsee Mark learns to survive. Umsee has a wolf that hunts with him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Probably 20 to 25 years ago. It was a published novel in the book store. Thanks

Comment: If he only traveled back 1000 years, he would be in Texas in 1000 AD. That would not be pre-historic. There would be no white men in that time in USA, just American Indian tribes. Is Umsee a tribe or a person?

Comment: Do you recall any info on the story? events that took place? things he did? what the cover might have looked like? Paperback or Hardback?

Comment: How old were you when you read it? Were you young? Could it have been a YA book?

Comment: I was probably in my late 30s. The book came from the sci-fi section of Tower Books back then. It was a fully published novel. I just can’t remember the title or author. Thanks

Comment: Umsee was the early Indian caretaker of the Hot Springs are for the families that only wintered there. 
The main character Mark was struck by lightning in modern day Dallas and woke up in primitive Texas. He travels east. Crossing the Red River he is caught in a bad flash flood. He continues on east because he and his wife had been to Hot Springs Arkansas in modern times. He knew it would be mild during the winter. He meets Umsee. Through Umsee Mark learns to survive. Umsee has a wolf that hunts with him.

Comment: Bloody google couldn't tell the difference between Umsee and Um-see, dammit

Answer (score 13):

This is *[Survivor](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6056597-survivor)* by Robert Steele Gray.

> Mark Lewellyn lived an easy life. He was carefully chosen as a suitable husband by his wife looking toward a lifetime of wealth. Mark worked from home and spent much of his free-time enjoying a luxurious lifestyle; complete with lounging in a recliner in his crisp white jogging suit while watching his favorite sports broadcast. Until one day, a lightening strike uprooted this overweight man from his modern day conveniences to a pre-historic America. Equipped with very little survival skills, Mark is driven by instinct (and a stellar swing of a few rocks at hand) to survive wild animals, freak storms, starvation, and rogue Indians. Eventually, he stumbles upon a man from a peaceful tribe of hunters and gatherers in which Mark learns the value of manual labor.
>
> [image]

[This review](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/survivor-a-modern-adventure_robert-steele-gray/966569/#edition=1888575&idiq=13665651) mentions his companion Um-see

> It is in the relationship between Um-See and Mark that Gray most
> surprises us and most stretches his own writing skills.

Comment: Survivor. This is the book I have been searching for. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RobertMcCormack - Don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the tick to the left

Answer (score 2):

[*The Transall Saga*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transall_Saga) (1998) by Gary Paulsen?

> While hiking through the mountains, thirteen-year old Mark Harrison is brought to an alien world where he must survive the new terrain and conflict with the planet's indigenous people.
>
> [image]

He thinks he's in the past, but it turns out it's the future.

Comment: That is not the one I am looking for but looks very interesting. I will give it a read. Thanks

Comment: I've taken the liberty of swapping the amazon link for one from Wikipedia with the correct publishing date and a blurb about the book